# Exporting private_bytes of a X25519PrivateKey

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cryptography

Python's `cryptography` module defines the `X25519PrivateKey` and `X25519PublicKey` classes. But while `X25519PublicKey` has a `public_bytes()` method for serialization, a corresponding `private_bytes` method on `X25519PrivateKey` is missing.

Strangely, a `_from_private_bytes()` classmethod is present, suggesting some way of exporting the key.

How can I export the private key for saving?

Context: I need this for a [`noiseprotocol`](https://github.com/plizonczyk/noiseprotocol) connection with static public keys (`Noise_XX_*`) where I need to provide pre-generated and persisted keys.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think you're supposed to store that key.

Comment: Should that not be up to the implementation? Also, there is the `_from_private_bytes()` methods. And other EC private keys can be serialized (see `cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.ec._EllipticCurvePrivateKey`) why not this one?